# Legend inside octave's plot is covered / not in front

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I'm pretty new in working with Octave, but I'm nearly okay with my plotting results in general. There is only one thing I can't deal with: When I'm putting the legend inside the plot - which is necessary in some cases - it's not in front but covered by the plot itself.

[image: Screenshot of the pdf saved by the code]

Maybe the solution is obvious and I just can't see. But maybe it has to do with my setup: I already spend hours on it to have special characters (e.g. greek and german umlauts), subscripts, a two-lined title, the fonttypes and -sizes I need, and - most important - be able to save it correctly in vectors (pdf).
The result is a piece of code which is surely not best practice, and maybe somewhere in it is the reason for my actual problem with the legend.
And - last but not least - I'm working with Kubuntu 18.04, Octave 4.2.2, GNU Plot 5.2 patchlevel 2.

```
clear;clc;close all;
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")

t = (-2*pi:2*pi);

set(gca,'FontName','Helvetica');
set(gca, "fontsize", 32);
set(0,'DefaultTextInterpreter','tex');

plot(
      t,sin(t),'k-','LineWidth',4,
      t,sin(t)+1,'k-','LineWidth',4,
      t,sin(t)-1,'k-','LineWidth',4
);

set(gca, "fontsize", 34);
xlabel('Länge in \mum \rightarrow')
ylabel('Breite in \mu m \rightarrow')

set(gca, "fontsize", 20);
legend({
      'h_{räf,mean} \rho(t) \mu \mum',
      'h_{räf,mean} \rho(t) \mu \mum',
      'h_{räf,mean} \rho(t) \mu \mum'
      },"location", "east"
);

set(gca, "fontsize", 40);
title("Widerstand\n Kennlinie");

print ('legend-covered_example.pdf', '-dpdfcairo', "-S1200,600");
```

Comment: This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but does `set(leg ,'Layer', 'Top')` work? (where `leg=legend({...})`).

Comment: Hi! No, it seems to have no effect here.

Comment: Well. Something similar works in `Matlab`. I was hoping it works also in `octave`. Probably the same functionality has not been implemented or probably someone else here will come up with an answer. :)

Comment: Yes, thank you still.    set(leg,'color','white') does not help as well.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in my setup, legend appears on top normally for me.

Comment: this seems to be specific to the gnuplot toolkit. any reason you can't use another toolkit?

Comment: I need to use gnuplot (as far as I found out) because of the mentioned requirement to have special characters etc. in the saved vector-file. This was only given with pdfcairo, and that only works with gnuplot here.

Comment: fyi: If I run your code with the 'qt' toolkit, the umlauts appear as expected.  (also, if you want to reply to someone explicitly in stack overflow, type `@` and then start typing their surname, it will give you the option to choose their name so they will be notified of your reply )

Comment: @SardarUsama hah, I meant to say username. Freudian slip :)

Comment: @Tas I was mistaken. Min 3 letters are required. See details on tagging [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Thank you! Unfortunately, in my setup it's not working: The qt-plot looks pretty good, but the .pdf file made of it cannot be created like this: `error: print.m: PDFCAIRO output is not available for GL2PS output `